# How to activate a conda env automatically in VSC on windows using bash?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying all day to debug a code using Visual Studio Code without success. I have installed VSC on windows and I have installed bash (ubuntu) as well. I already put `bash` as a terminal default shell:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"
```

The thing is when I run the debug, it tries to activate the env with `activate myenv-name` and I couldn't find how to change this instruction to `source activate myenv-name`.

Do you know how I can do this? any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this question and I got the answer finally. :)

It is simple we just have to create `.bashrc` file in our user folder there we can write whatever commands we need to run each time we start a terminal in `vscode`.

Here the command to activate a conda env:

`source activate myenv_name`

In case of `bash: conda: command not found` and you don't have admin permissions to change the paths use this command before `source act...`:

`export PATH=$"/c/Users/UserName/AnacondaPath/Scripts":$PATH`